# Adding Set<String> value to a new Set<String> collection

Tags: java, string, set

Here is my code method whic is in class "dictionary":

```
    private Map<String, Set<String>> kaannokset;                       
    public OmaUseanKaannoksenSanakirja() {
        this.kaannokset= new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(String word, String translate) {
        kaannokset.putIfAbsent(word, new HashSet<>());       
        kaannokset.get(word).add(translate);
    }                           
    public Set<String> translate(String word) {
        Set<String> listaus = new HashSet<>();
        if (kaannokset.containsKey(word)) {
            listaus.add(kaannokset.get(word).toString());
        } else {
            listaus.add("");
        }
    return listaus;
}
```

When I try to call my method for example:

```
dictionary.translate("six");
//output: [[sex]]
```

I know that the the extra square brackets are result because I'm calling toString() for Set. How I can get rid of the extra square brackets from my output? My goal output is:

```
dictionary.translate("six");
//goal output:
//[sex]
```

Comment: I don't see the variable `dictionary` appearing anywhere in your code.  Can you fix your question so that it is clear?

Comment: Edited now @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Are you looking for `listaus.addAll(kaannokset.get(word))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the result to contain a single string which is the toString() representation of the original set stored in the map. You want it to be... the set stored in the map, right?

So, if you really want to return an empty set in case the map doesn't contain the key, you can just use

```
return kaannokset.getOrDefault(word, Collections.singleton(""));
```

But I really don't understand why you would like an empty string in the set. I would just return an empty set in this case:

```
return kaannokset.getOrDefault(word, Collections.emptySet());
```